# How to ignore level @RequestMapping() and direct call method level @RequestMapping()?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, request-mapping

How to do I ignore the class level `@RequestMapping("/home")` and directly call the method level `@RequestMapping("/users")` in Spring?

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/home")

@RequestMapping("/method1")
public void method1(){
...
}

@RequestMapping("/users")
public void listUsers(){
...
}
```

I want to call `http://localhost:8080/users` to invoke `listUsers()` method.

Comment: Would `../users` work? I'm just contemplating but it's worth a try

Comment: This does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot bypass requestmapping defined at class level. for If so why you want a class level mapping then... you can instead do something like this in the method level request mapping

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/home/method1")
public void method1(){
...
}

@RequestMapping("/users")
public void listUsers(){
...
}
```

In that case you may try this...

```
 @Controller
@RequestMapping({ "/home", "/users" })


    @RequestMapping("/method1")
    public void method1(){
    ...
    }

   @RequestMapping(method="RequestMethod.GET")
    public void listUsers(){
    ...
    }
```

Comment: I've various other methods in this Controller class which are a part of legacy code and I cannot touch that, while Im writing my new Endpoints I do not want to call the class-level @RequestMapping for my methods.

Comment: try the updated approach in my answer and let me know if it works..in that I have just mapped multiple request mappings at class level and so removed the one from your method as it's not needed

Comment: How does it know which one it should map to? Like /home/method1 for method1() and /users for listUsers(). Suppose I've /users/(id}, then how to do exact mapping?

Comment: params {} cant be mapped at class level, for that you handle it by mapping one more requestmapping in your case i will make that as /users/getUserById/{id}. So now my /users remains at class level and /getUserById/{id} goes to method level

Answer (score 0):

Change `@RequestMapping("/users")` for `@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)`

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, what you expect is a **class-level** RequestMapping. The **method-level** RequestMapping should be under the path of **class-level**'s.

I'll give you some examples:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/home")
public class HomeController {
    // Full path of following endpoint: /home/parents.
    @RequestMapping(value = "/parents", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<List<People>> getParents() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(methodToGetParents());
}
```

For the path of "users" you should do it in another class (controller):

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UsersController {
    // Full path of following endpoint: /users.
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<List<People>> getUsers() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(methodToGetUsers());
}
```

Comment: I've various other methods in this Controller class which are a part of legacy code and I cannot touch that, while Im writing my new Endpoints I do not want to call the class-level @RequestMapping for my methods.

Comment: @user2340345 If you are trying to use some HomeController's methods in your "/users" endpoint, I think these methods are written in the wrong place. Because from my understanding, controller class shouldn't contains too much logic code. These methods should be moved to a service class.